# Why am I obtaining this error message trying to use map() function in an Angular project? Cannot find name 'map'

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9

I am working on an Angular project and I am finding the following problem in this class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SidebarModule} from 'primeng/sidebar';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  display;

  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
  isLoggedOut$:Observable<boolean>;
  pictureUrl$: Observable<string>;


  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => console.log(user));

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => !!user));

    this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map(loggedIn => !loggedIn));

    this.pictureUrl$ =
      this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => user ? user.photoURL: null));
  }


  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

The problem appears on the **map()** call of these 3 lines:

```
this.isLoggedIn$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => !!user));

this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map(loggedIn => !loggedIn));

this.pictureUrl$ =
  this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => user ? user.photoURL: null));
```

The IDE give me this error message:

```
Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?ts(2552)
lib.es2015.collection.d.ts(36, 13): 'Map' is declared here.
```

Trying to compile I am obtaining this error message:

```
ERROR in src/app/header/header.component.ts:25:51 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

25     this.isLoggedIn$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => !!user));
                                                     ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:36:13
    36 declare var Map: MapConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Map' is declared here.
src/app/header/header.component.ts:27:47 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

27     this.isLoggedOut$ = this.isLoggedIn$.pipe(map(loggedIn => !loggedIn));
                                                 ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:36:13
    36 declare var Map: MapConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Map' is declared here.
src/app/header/header.component.ts:30:34 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?

30       this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(user => user ? user.photoURL: null));
                                    ~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:36:13
    36 declare var Map: MapConstructor;
                   ~~~
    'Map' is declared here.
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this code?

Comment: You're missing an import...

Comment: You have to import `map` like this: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import RxJS `map` operator: `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Ok, done...it works...but why the IDE don't give me the TIP to import this as done for all the other import?

Comment: which IDE do you use?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code, for all others import give me the hint, for this no...